# Mongodb search query with populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

hello I have 3 collections in MongoDB, Client AgentLetter, and a lawyer

**Client**

```
{
_id:"62bd0d557e6411a15d809bb4"
,FirstName:"John",
LastName:"Doe",
Mobile":"182-333-8822",
"Active":true,
}
```

**Lawyer**

```
{
_id:"62bd0d557e6411a15d809bb4",
 email:johndoe@gmail.com,
,FirstName:"John",
LastName:"Doe",
Mobile":"182-333-8822",
"Active":true,
}
```

**Agentletter**

```
{
_id:"62bd0d557e6411a15d809bb4",
client: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'client' }],
lawyer: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'lawyer' }],
number:"Doe",
type:"all",
placeOut:"Suli-court",
note:""
}
```

And I have search input on agentletter table that relates to client and lawyer
when the user searches for something like "John" return document with lawyer
client if text not match **placeOut** **FirstName** and **LastName** return []
I tried this but on some occasions didn't work and it cants get placeOut on agentletter

```
 AgentLetter.find().populate({ 
    path  : 'lawyer client',
    select:"FirstName LastName",
    match : {
          $or:[
     { FirstName : {
          $regex: req.params.text, 
          $options: 'i' 
      }},
      { LastName : {
        $regex: req.params.text, 
        $options: 'i' 
    }},
// { placeOut : {
//       $regex: req.params.text, 
//       $options: 'i' 
//    }},
    ]
  }}).exec()
```

Anyone an idea how to solve this? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [aggregate pipelines](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate) to query from multiple collections.

The solution could be:

```js
  AgentLetter.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "clients",
        localField: "client",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "client"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "lawyers",
        localField: "lawyer",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "lawyer"
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
        $or: [
          {
            "client.FirstName": {
              $regex: req.params.text,
              $options: "i"
            }
          },
          {
            "client.LastName": {
              $regex: req.params.text,
              $options: "i"
            }
          },
          {
            "lawyer.FirstName": {
              $regex: req.params.text,
              $options: "i"
            }
          },
          {
            "lawyer.LastName": {
              $regex: req.params.text,
              $options: "i"
            }
          },
          {
            placeOut: {
              $regex: req.params.text,
              $options: "i"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]).exec();
```